# Commutator of free products of groups

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups, free-product

Let $G$ be a free product of nontrivial groups $H_i$: $G=H_1\ast\cdots\ast H_n.$

Let $g_1,g_2\in G$ be such elements that: 1) $g_1,g_2\not\in H_k^g$ for all $g\in G$ and $k=1,\ \dots,\ n$; 2) $[g_1,g_2]=g_1g_2g_1^{-1}g_2^{-1}\ne 1$.

Is it true that $[g_1,g_2] \not\in H_k^g$ for all $g\in G$ and $k=1,\ \dots,\ n$?

Comment: Just a thought, but maybe it would be easier to prove that if a nontrivial commutator $[g_1, g_2] \in H_k^g$ for some $g \in G$ and $k$, then at least one of $g_1$ and $g_2$ has to be contained in a component $H_h^g$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sketch of proof:

- $G$ acts on its Bass-Serre tree $T$. Since the vertex-stabilisers are precisely the conjugates of the free factors, your assumption 1 precisely means that $g_1$ and $g_2$ are loxodromic isometries of $T$.
- For $i=1,2$, let $\ell_i$ denote the axis of $g_i$. Since $g_1$ and $g_2$ do not commute, $\ell_1 \neq \ell_2$.
- Prove that the commutator $[g_1,g_2]$ is also a loxodromic element, meaning that $[g_1,g_2]$ does not belong to the conjugate of some free factor.